# Google Places Autocomplete API 'types' parameter only works with establishment?

Tags: types, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Place's Autocomplete API in my app but am having an issue filtering the results to specific types (i.e. `restaurant`).

Anytime I change the `types` parameter to something other than `establishment`, I get an `INVALID_REQUEST` response.

However, when I do a standard search of all restaurants nearby, the results that show up match the same autocomplete results.

*Example: Applebee's at 555 Saratoga Avenue, San Jose, CA shows up in my `nearby` search and my `autocomplete` search, but only has the type `establishment` in the `autocomplete` API response while it has `restaurant` in the standard search API response.*

Anyone else encounter this issue or know of a workaround? The API Docs make it sound like all valid types should be acceptable in the autocomplete API request.

Here is my URL using `type=restaurant` which always fails:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?types=restaurant&input=applebee&radius=48280.2&rankby=distance&key=MY_API_KEY&location=37.33233141,-122.0312186
```

Here is the URL using `type=establishment` that works:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?types=establishment&input=applebee&radius=48280.2&rankby=distance&key= MY_API_KEY&location=37.33233141,-122.0312186
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The types you can use for autocomplete is more restricted than those that you can use for search. "restaurant" isn't a valid place type for autocomplete. The valid types are:

- geocode
- establishment
- address
- (regions)
- (cities)

See [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types) in the docs for more info.

Comment: This is correct (unfortunately). Was hoping there was a way to use any type but guess not. Thanks.

Comment: does **regions** really work? I am not able to make requests through **regions** type

Comment: Sorry. It's "(regions)", not  "regions". I've updated the answer.

Comment: (regions) doesn't work for me either, not showing any results whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the **restaurant** type  parameter not work in  `/place/autocomplete/json`

if you want to find "restaurant"  `place/textsearch/json?`

search text after add  **+**

Example  1 :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurant+applebee&key={API_KEY}
```

Example 2 :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=48.859294,2.347589&radius=5000&type=cafe&keyword=vegetarian&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

for multiple type use `types=food|restaurant`

for more information 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search